# Starting mix task process dependencies

Tags: elixir

New to Elixir but loving it so far :)

A lot of my mix tasks depend on HTTPotion.

My `mix.exs` file is declared as such

```
  def application do
    [
      applications: [:logger, :cowboy, :plug, :httpotion, :poison],
      mod: {BiddingAgent, []}
    ]
  end
```

So HTTPotion.start is called automatically. However, when I run a task like `mix campaign.list` which needs to call an http request, I have to manually call `HTTPotion.start`.

What is the idiomatic way to make sure the right processes are started for my mix tasks?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added HTTPotion to your dependency list?

Comment: Looking at `mix test` and seeing that you must have `ExUnit.start` in one of your `exs` files when running tests, I'd guess that you'll need to do the same thing with other applications that need to be started when running a mix task. I'd be happy if I was wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're right, when starting the app outside of the startup script you do need to start the dependencies manually.

I prefer to call the `Application` module instead of each dependency directly.

Add the following code to the `run` function inside your task module.

```
{:ok, _started} = Application.ensure_all_started(:httpotion)
```

If you have any doubt you can take a look at the [documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html#ensure_all_started/2)

Edit:
The practice described is being used in Ecto

- https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/master/lib/mix/ecto.ex#L73
- https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/df13b1c64f8edd128cec1316336b20f3153eafa3/lib/mix/tasks/ecto.migrate.ex#L67

A module is included in a the mix tasks which provides an ensure_started method.