# get only prod mix dependencies

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Having:

```
  defp deps do
    [
      {:poison, "~> 3.0"},
      {:credo, "~> 0.10.0", only: [:dev, :test], runtime: false}
    ]
  end
```

I am doing something like this to ensure all dependencies are started:

```
MixProject.project()
|> Keyword.get(:deps)
|> Keyword.keys()
|> Enum.each(fn dep ->
  Application.ensure_all_started(dep)
end
```

But is crashing with `:dev` dependencies like credo.

Can I retreive `:prod` only dependencies? since filtering out only: `[:dev, :test], runtime: false` is a bit tricky

Comment: Does passing your app's name to `Application.ensure_all_started` not work? Starting your app will start all your dependencies if they're not started.

Comment: this is intended for mix tasks where my app is not running

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706320/starting-mix-task-process-dependencies but I added all the dependencies because I have a lot of mandatory dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, about the reason you're getting an error. In your example this invocation

```
MixProject.project()
|> Keyword.get(:deps)
```

returns a `List` and not a `Keyword List` which is what the next line expects

```
|> Keyword.keys()
```

That's why it crashes with what can be assumed to be

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/1 in Keyword.keys/1
```

As you pointed out it crashes specifically on those dependencies that are not described by a two-item tuple and therefore do not represent elements of a `Keyword List`.

---

Now to the core of your question. As you pointed out you could filter the deps manually but scenarios like these make it rather tedious to do:

```
{:dep_one, "~> 1.0"},
{:dep_two, "~> 1.0", only: [:prod]},
{:dep_three, "~> 1.0", except: [:dev, :test]}
```

An alternative is to build your deps list dynamically depending on the environment, e.g.:

```
defp deps do
  [
    # universal deps go here
  ] ++ deps(Mix.env)
end

defp deps(env) when env == :dev do
  [
    # dev-only deps
  ]
end
defp deps(env) when env == :test do
  [
    # test-only deps
  ]
end
defp deps(env) when env == :prod do
  [
    # prod-only deps
  ]
end
```

This simplistic implementation would require duplicate definitions of the deps defined for multiple environments, such as `only: [:dev, :test]`, but it could be reworked to avoid that.